# Using arrays in typoscript

Tags: arrays, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript, associated-object

I'm quite new to typoscript and I want to use an array to associate a subject to an email adress like this

```
email_mapper {
   general = info@somewhere.com
   specific = me@somewhere.com
}

to_mail = email_mapper[GP:formhandler|subject]
```

how can I do something like that in typoscript? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the [CASE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Case/Index.html) content object. It would look somehow like this:

```
to_mail = CASE
to_mail {
    key.data = GP:formhandler|subject

    general = TEXT
    general.value = info@somewhere.com

    specific = TEXT
    specific.value = me@somewhere.com

    default = TEXT
    default.value = catchall@somewhere.com
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, but something along these lines will work.

Comment: I think CASE is the right thing to use, but suddenly TYPO3 always takes the first one (which is the general email) and the default case gets ignored completly.

Comment: OK, that was a TYPO3 cache issue. your script works just fine :)

Comment: Please read the section about `CASE` in the `TypoScript Reference`.